# PHP interface to specify object return value requirements?

Tags: php, class, implements

Is there a way to implement an interface for an object in PHP 5.5, such that the required methods return a specific value? I can see the value in interfaces for making code portable by using them to ensuring the methods we call from object instances are present; however, this does not ensure the implementation of the interface will return the desired value.

For instance, if we have an interface such as the following:

```
interface myInterface {
    public function multiply($var1, $var2);
}
```

...and have this implemented in our code with an existing object that multiplies $var1 and $var2 to return some floating point value, our program's code will expect to handle a float in order to function correctly. This being the case, how do we prevent a new object that uses this same template from doing something like the following:

```
class newClass implements myInterface {
    public function multiply($var1, $var2) {
        return "WAHOO!!!"
    }
}
```

In this case, our code expecting a float will get "WAHOO!!!" and will not run correctly. Is there a way to ensure that the new class both require the "multiply" method and have this method return a float, regardless of how the class is coded?

Comment: This answer may help. Looks like it isn't possible, which kind of fits php in general: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048179/why-is-it-possible-to-have-an-interface-without-a-return-type-in-php

Comment: The same reason that you don't specify the types of `$var1` and `$var2`. PHP in general doesn't do compile-time type checking.

Comment: @Chizzle - Yet... https://wiki.php.net/rfc/return_types

Comment: as well as https://wiki.php.net/rfc/scalar_type_hints_v5 for parameter type definition